# Can I have my header's background color fade in as the page scrolls down

Tags: jquery, colors, background, scroll, opacity

First off, here's my website: [my website](http://andrewdurano.com)

I was hoping to get some feedback on how to have my header's background color (light grey) fade from 0 opacity to 100% as the page gets scrolled down. Maybe right before the first project hits the header, the grey background will have appeared already.

On my project pages, you can see that the sidebar description fades after a certain point. I want that for my header, but not the whole div to be invisible at first, but just the background color.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and bind function to event `scroll`

```javascript
$(document).bind("scroll", function() {

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var max = $(document).height() - $(window).height(); // Max avilable scroll position
    var header = $("#header");

    header.css("opacity", scrollPos / max);
    // OR
    header.css("opacity", 1 - (scrollPos / max));
});
```

Comment: Correct ,I was creating this fiddle, it is almost the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/xDWQa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and upvote to @jjurm who posted the answer earlier, here is a bit cleaner and better example:

```
$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
    var scrolly = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
     $("#header").css("opacity", scrolly / height +.3);
});
```

Variables:
scrolly : amount of pixels scrolled on y axis,
height: document height - window height

+.3 will keep the minimum opacity so your header will still be there if you scroll back up.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDWQa/1/

Comment: Thanks! i'll plug it in and see how it goes